# Как отправить запрос чтобы подгрузить картинки?

Tags: android, recyclerview, запрос

Добрый вечер.

У меня есть RecyclerView, в который я с сайта спарсил картинки, но спарсились они не все, т.к. на сайте есть кнопка "Загрузить еще", которая подгружает еще партию картинок на сайт. Мне нужно, чтобы все картинки с сайта были в моем RecyclerView.

Ранее мне подсказали, что нужно отправлять такой же запрос из приложения, какой отправляет сайт при нажатии на кнопку "Загрузить еще", чтобы загрузить еще картинок. Но как это сделать в Android - ума не приложу. Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, какие-нибудь библиотеки или варианты решения данной задачи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам надо:

1. Открыть нужную страницу в браузере
2. Открыть консоль разработчика браузера
3. Нажать на кнопку, подгружающую элементы.
4. В консоли отобразится происходящее - т.е. сетевой запрос с типом, параметрами, заголовками, адресом
5. Далее берёте к-л либу для отправки сетевых запросов и повторяете в точности отправляемый браузером запрос.
6. Стартовать запрос в андроиде надо повесив на список слушатель скрола, отслеживающий промотку к концу списка (см. google->`endlessscrolling listview/recyclerview/scrollview`)
7. После получения нужных данных надо обновить ими список данных адаптера и уведомить его о необходимости перерисоваться.

Comment: Юрий, спасибо Вам большое за помощь!